# render complex org chart similar javascript/flash/java graphic library

Tags: java, javascript, flash, graph, visualization

i am looking for javascript/flash/java graphic lib. that able to render nicely a very complex relationship where one node is relate to another node etc. for example

a--> b---> c

b--> d,e,f

any recommandation library?

Comment: So essentially you are looking for recommendations for a graph visualization library for Javascript, Flash, or Java?

Comment: yes.i am looking for graph visualization lib

Answer (score 3):

[Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) is very cool and Java based.

Demo [here](http://www.enronexplorer.com/focus/19185#).

Answer (score 2):

what a cooincidence, I was just looking into this myself. I found this:
http://www.ryandesign.com/canviz/

http://code.google.com/p/canviz/

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I use for Organizational chart

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) open source graph visualization software is widely used to render graphs, and [jGraphviz](http://jgraphviz.sourceforge.net/) is a binding for java.